# How to join data from NHGIS to make choropleth maps in R/ggplot2?

Tags: shapefile, r, attribute-joins, merge, ggplot2

I have downloaded shapefiles of county/state boundaries and census data keyed to those shapefiles from the [NHGIS](https://www.nhgis.org/). Both the shapefiles and the census data have a `GISJOIN` column to be used for merging the data. I'm able to do this just fine in QGIS, but I can't for the life of me get it to work in R/ggplot2.

This is what the data looks like:

```
str(churches_1850)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  30 variables:
 $ GISJOIN : Factor w/ 36 levels "G010","G050",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ YEAR    : int  1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 1850 ...
 $ STATE   : Factor w/ 36 levels "Alabama","Arkansas",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ STATEA  : int  10 50 60 90 100 110 120 130 170 180 ...
 $ COUNTY  : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ COUNTYA : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AREANAME: Factor w/ 36 levels "Alabama","Arkansas",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ AET001  : int  579 114 1 114 12 6 56 885 282 430 ...
 $ AET002  : int  18 NA NA 4 NA NA NA 5 69 187 ...
 $ AET003  : int  NA NA NA 252 NA NA NA 1 46 2 ...
 $ AET004  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AET005  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 5 ...
 $ AET006  : int  17 2 1 101 21 8 10 20 27 24 ...
 $ AET007  : int  5 1 NA 1 NA NA 1 6 2 10 ...
 $ AET008  : int  NA NA NA 5 9 1 NA 2 6 89 ...
 $ AET009  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 3 5 ...
 $ AET010  : int  NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AET011  : int  1 NA NA NA NA 2 NA 8 42 63 ...
 $ AET012  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AET013  : int  577 168 5 185 106 16 87 809 405 779 ...
 $ AET014  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 1 2 57 ...
 $ AET015  : int  162 52 3 17 26 6 16 97 206 282 ...
 $ AET016  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 NA NA NA ...
 $ AET017  : int  5 7 18 12 3 6 5 8 59 63 ...
 $ AET018  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 2 NA ...
 $ AET019  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 4 5 ...
 $ AET020  : int  4 5 NA 4 1 NA NA 16 30 5 ...
 $ AET021  : int  1 NA NA 5 NA 1 NA NA 4 1 ...
 $ AET022  : int  3 NA NA 22 NA NA NA 3 7 15 ...
 $ AET023  : int  3 13 NA 10 2 NA NA 7 25 13 ...
```

This is what I'm trying so far:

```
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
states_1850 <-readOGR(dsn = "shp/nhgis0007_shapefile_tl2000_us_state_1850/",
                        layer = "US_state_1850")
churches_1850 <- read.csv("csv/nhgis0007_ds10_1850_state.csv")
states_1850_df <- fortify(states_1850, region = "GISJOIN")
states_with_data <- merge(states_1850_df, churches_1850, by.x="id", by.y="GISJOIN")

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=states_with_data,
               aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=AET001)) +
  coord_map()
```

I've tried a number of other ways of merging the data, but they all either end up not merging correctly, or tearing the shapes of the states/counties, or being so large that plotting them crashes my machine (8GB ram, shouldn't be a problem).

This seems like it should be easier. What's the proper way to do this?

**UPDATE:** This method of merging data frames seems to be the older way of doing things. Using `geom_map` is much more powerful, since it merges the data on the fly rather than at the beginning. It also allows for easier faceting. See the [ggplot2 docs for geom_map](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_map.html).

My revised plotting code looks like this:

```
p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = churches_1850, 
           aes(map_id = GISJOIN, fill = AET015),
           map = shp_1860, size=0.01, alpha=.9) +
  expand_limits(x = shp_1860$long, y=shp_1860$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", high="red")
print(p)
```

Comment: It might help to include a description of the results you are getting, and how they are in error.  Could it have to do with the order that you are merging the layers together?  If you switch `states_1850_df` and `churches_1850` and their respective columns in the `merge` command, does it make a difference?

Comment: I notice that `GISJOIN` is a *factor*. Does it have the same levels and use identical codes in both files? If not, see the `R` help for `factor` and `as.factor` for how to make them match. Alternatively, study the help for `read.csv` for how to keep this field as a string type.

Comment: Could it be that you need to set `sort = FALSE` in the `merge` call, as per [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/37268/6328)?

Comment: @whuber: I tried setting the option `stringsAsFactors=F` for both the fortified shapefile data frame and the data frame with the actual data. That seemed to have helped.

Comment: @SlowLearner: I had tried `sort= FALSE` before and it didn't work now. But ordering the fortified data frame this way, did work: `d_1860 <-d_1860[order(d_1860$order),]`. If you leave an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I found a better way to do this using `geom_map` detailed in an update above.

Comment: If your solution works it may be worth using it as the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method of merging data frames seems to be the older way of doing things. Using geom_map is much more powerful, since it merges the data on the fly rather than at the beginning. It also allows for easier faceting. See the [ggplot2 docs for geom_map](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_map.html).

My revised plotting code looks like this:

```
shp_1860 <- readOGR("/home/lmullen/research-data/nhgis-shapefiles/county_1860_simple/",
                    "US_county_1860",
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

shp_1860 <- fortify(shp_1860, region="GISJOIN")

c_1860 <- read.csv("~/research-data/nhgis-religion/ds14_1860_county.csv",
                   stringsAsFactors=F)

p <- ggplot() + 
  geom_map(data = c_1860, 
           aes(map_id = GISJOIN, fill = AET015),
           map = shp_1860) +
  expand_limits(x = shp_1860$long, y=shp_1860$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="white", high="red")
print(p)
```